# display two different Toast

Tags: android, multithreading, toast

I want to display two different Toast. The second one shall appear 8 seconds after the second one.

I tried to code this :

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Toast toast1 = new Toast(context);
    Toast toast2 = new Toast(context);

    //toast1
    toast1.makeText(context, "First toast ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    //wait for 8 seconds
        try {
            Thread.sleep(8000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    //toast2
    toast2.makeText(context, "Toast2 ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Unfortunately, only the second toast appears. I don't know if the error is from my wrong use of toast or my wrong use of threads !

Thank you

Comment: It's amusing to see @JackOnF1re posted the correct answer first and others just copy pasting it. O_@

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't just stop the UI Thread. 
Use a Handler (Android way) or TimerTask (Java way) for this.

```
 Handler h = new Handler();
    h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(someContext, "someText", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }, 8000);
```

Comment: thanks! it works! can you please take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32129959/callbacks-in-android-to-program-beacon ? perhaps you give me another idea, thanx again

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) .

A `Handler allows you to send and process Message and Runnable objects` associated with a thread's MessageQueue. Each Handler instance is associated with a single thread and that thread's message queue.

```
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast toast1 = new Toast(context);
        Toast toast2 = new Toast(context);

      toast1.makeText(context, "First toast ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   

      Handler handler = new Handler(); 
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
                     public void run() { 

                  toast2.makeText(context, "Toast2 ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();     

                     } 
                }, 8000);
```

Comment: Your answer is "kind of" wrong. :) If you use postDelayed, you need to send the first Toast before the handler usage, and the second one inside of the runnable.

Answer (score 0):

Stopping the UI thread is not possible. You have to use some Handlers for this.

```
Handler handler = new Handler(); 
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
     public void run() { 
           toast1.makeText(context, "First toast ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

     } 
}, 8000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I Simply Put

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context,"First",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        try{
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        }catch(Exception e){

        }
        Toast.makeText(context,"Second",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

And it Worked...
But My suggestion is you should not stop UI Thread, Use Handler as @IntelliJ Amiya said.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code with this:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Toast toast1 = new Toast(context);
    Toast toast2 = new Toast(context);

    //toast1
    toast1.makeText(context, "First toast", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    //toast2
    Handler handler = new Handler(); 
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
        public void run() { 
            toast2.makeText(context, "Second toast", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } 
    }, 8000);
}
```